# How to go back to first page of app in flutter app?

Tags: dart, flutter

So I've created an app that has like 4 pages and then a webview so whenever a user logout from webview I push the starting screen.
I want my app to go to the first page. I've tried:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/welcomeScreen');
Navigator.popUntil(context,ModalRoute.withName('/welcomeScreen'));
```

but no luck. I think this may be because of webview.
This is my routes.

```
final routes = {
'/login': (BuildContext context) => new LoginScreen(),
'/home': (BuildContext context) => new HomeScreen(),
'/welcomeScreen':(BuildContext context) => new WelcomeScreen(),
'/email': (BuildContext context) => new EmailScreen(),
'/webview': (BuildContext context) => new WebviewScreen()
};
```

Comment: Did the following answer work for you ? if it's can you accept the answer please!

Answer (score 9):

This function will set the page root page so it should work for logout case.

`Navigator.pushAndRemoveUnitl` is what are you looking for I guess.

```
void makeRoutePage({BuildContext context, Widget pageRef}) {
  Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => pageRef),
      (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
}
```

how to use it :

```
makeRoutePage(context: context, pageRef: YourFirstPage());
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to go back through all screens until the first screen in Stack, so best statement you can use is:

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, (Route<dynamic> predicate) => predicate.isFirst);
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use this code in any button action, it will redirect U to MainScreen/Homepage from any other page

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution can be `Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'));` which will pop all screens from the stack except the initial screen.